# PDO error checking for SQL queries

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am trying to add more error outputs to my code as it is growing. But I am not sure how deep I need to go. For instance, if I send a PDO DELETE FROM command to a table, is it necessary for me to then query the table again to see if the row was deleted (and confirm to the user)? Or should I rely on error handling, as in, if there was no error, it was definitely successful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap every SQL statement in a try and catch block to see if any SQL exceptions or any other exceptions occured.

Depending on how you execute your PDO queries you have two options.

You can execute a statement directly with the PDO class using the exec() function. This function will return the number of affected rows for each query. However this function does not return the number of affected rows for an SELECT query.

So for delete queries you would use

```
$connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$affectedRows = $connection->exec('DELETE from users WHERE id = 1);
```

This way affectedRows will probably be 1 or 0 if the user doesn't exist. If any other errors occur the catch part of the try-catch block will make sure to fetch these.

If you want to execute an SELECT query and find out if it was successful I would recommend doing this

```
$connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$statement = $connection->prepare(SELECT * FROM users);
$statement->execute();
$returnedUsers = $statement->fetchAll();
```

As you can see, calling the method $connection->prepare() will return a statement which is an object of the PDOStatement class.

If you have parameters set in the prepare query you would want to set these through the bindParam() methods of the PDOStatement class.

Keep in mind that when it's neccesary to execute multiple similar queries in one go use an object of PDOStatement and then set different parameters using the bindParam() method.

Comment: Ok great, I already do all of that. Just making sure. Thanks!

Comment: I personally set errormode attribute on the connection, no need to catch error will be thrown